# fixed column of html table breaks layout

Tags: html, css

i need to  create a table with the first column fixed and the rest of the columns scrollable horizontally.

I managed to implement this successfully BUT when i implement it in my website it doesn't seem to be working.

when i make the table head fixed, the first column breaks the layout

when i use this with a plain table it works but not with my theme

```
.table-wrapper th:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}
```

Table which works without the css : http://www.vidznet.com/table/2.html

Table with css : http://www.vidznet.com/table/1.htm

can someone tell me what might be conflicting?

Update:
what i need is the first column to be fixed and the scrollbar to start from the second column like this

It should be like this: http://vidznet.com/table/table1.jpg

but in my css theme it looks like this  http://vidznet.com/table/table2.jpg

Comment: mind uploading a picture of how its supposed to look like? layouts of both tables look the same to me.

Comment: @Banana added image links

Comment: for a start, you might want to change the `"position"` of `.table-wrapper th:first-child` to **"absolute"** instead of **"fixed"**

Comment: sorry.. Please check this link http://www.vidznet.com/table/likethis.jpg This is how i want it to look like.

Comment: @Banana i did that but the first header seems messed..

Comment: is the table supposed to be responsive? or it's size will be constant?

Comment: responsive.. i made it using bootstrap...

Comment: you can set what i wrote above to absolute, and then remove all paddings from `.table > thead > tr > th` and adjust `.table.table-striped > thead:first-child > tr > th:first-child{width: 9.6%; text-align: left; height: 24%; }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your CSS property:

```
.table.table-striped > thead:first-child > tr > th:first-child {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

The width is too large for the column. It needs to be changed to 5 to 12%, depending on how you want how far you want the underline to go, to fit in with the other fixed elements.

Comment: even i change the width it doesnt fit well :(

Comment: If you're only problem is the investment side overflowing, I believe this is the solution. Try using the inspect element property of Chrome (right click>Inspect Element on Windows). If you right click the investment tab and change that particular CSS width property. it does fit, or atleast does in my browser (Chrome). Or you can get rid of the width property altogether, and it should fit. Here's a picture of it working on my browser: http://imgur.com/wMgMzWN